# How to use ROW_NUMBER() in SQLite?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to get the row number from a SQLite database **with SQLAlchemy**?

```
row_num | ai_fld | name
-------------------------
1       | 1      | foo
2       | 2      | bar
3       | 5      | baz
```

I don't want to :

- create a temporary table
- use some kind of loop other a query of *all* items

Comment: Why do you want the row number?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I want to select from a range (SELECT .. WHERE rn > 4 AND rn < 21)

Comment: Why not use the PK for that?

Comment: eehmm... because the PK is not the same as the row number.

Comment: Then you need to explain why you need the row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select from a range of records, use the [LIMIT/OFFSET clauses](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset):

```sql
SELECT ai_fld,
       name
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ai_fld
LIMIT 16 OFFSET 4
```